# Curl Parsing in Ruby without Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, rest-client

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [simple parsing in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319221/simple-parsing-in-ruby)

I am trying to verify a title in a website and after some trial and error I have found that this can be done in ruby by using nokogiri and rest-client

```
 require 'nokogiri'
 require 'rest-client'

 page = Nokogiri::HTML(RestClient.get("http:/#{user.username}.domain.com/"))   
 simian = page.at_css("title").text 
     if simian == "Welcome to"
       puts "default monkey" 
   else 
   puts "website updated"       
    end
```

unfortunately for a large number of websites this doesn't always seems to work as it returns
RestClient::InternalServerError at /admin/users/list
500 Internal Server Error

I was wondering if there is any option to achieve the same by simply using 
mycurl =  %x(curl http://........) what would be an efficient way to use that by parsing the title and without using any gem or can the curl option be used directly with nokogiri ?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

After reading your question wasn't really sure if you are set with those 2 gems or not, here is another way that may prove simpler.

```
require 'open-uri'

url="http://google.com"
source = open(url).read
source[/<title>(.*)<\/title>, 1]
```

Comment: syntax error ?source[/<title>(.*)<\/title>, 1]

Answer (score 1):

There's two parts to this. One is fetching the page and the other is parsing. For fetching, you don't really need the `rest-client` gem, when `open-uri` from the standard library will do. Nokogiri does the parsing, and it is not likely your problem. Try this:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://example.com/'))
puts page.at('title').text
```

Comment: hello this works and many thanks - the only problem is if, for example, I am trying to open a page that in lieu of the index has no index and the server shows an internal server error the script dies with OpenURI::HTTPError at /admin/users/
500 Internal Server Error /ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb: in open_http
      raise OpenURI::HTTPError.new(io.status.join(' '), io)...
any hint on how to skip these pages would be much appreciated !!

Comment: does not work https://gist.github.com/3670329 URI cannot handle simple _ in subdomains so I have to use curl

Comment: @devnull In your first comment, the server is responding with the error, it's not coming from the open-uri code. As for your second comment, `_` is an invalid character in a domain name.

Comment: Re-reading your first comment, I guess you want to gracefully skip when open-uri throws an exception? Put the code in a `rescue` block.

Comment: _ is not an invalid character in a sub domain like me_me.1.ai and open-uri doesn't work with that even if is a completely legitimate sub domain